# How can I limit what m2m items are displayed in django template-side?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I have a queryset in a view limiting on an m2m field. The query appears to work correctly and gets the right parent objects, but when I loop through the parent.object_set.all in the template I see m2m objects that were technically not included in the initial query (or shouldn't be anyway), but now included because they are part of parent's child m2m object_set.

To try put this in a more generic example...I'm completely making up parents and children:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    children = models.ManyToManyField(Child)

class Child(models.Model):
    ...
    # no, I'm not serious on this as a data structure, but for the example....
    male = models.BooleanField()
    female = models.BooleanField()

class ParentListView(ListView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        parents = Parent.objects.filter(children__male = True)
```

In the template.

```
{% for parent in parents %}
    {{ parent.name }}
    {% for child in parent.child_set.all %}
        {% comment %}
            oops, I got all the children of this parent....I only want those that were male from the original queryset. I need the child_set to only be those that met the criteria in that first queryset. How do I accomplish this?
        {% endcomment %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: There are parents that have childrens male and female

Comment: You can't do it purely in a template. You need to either set the desired subset in the view or write a custom template tag to look them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't provide filter arguments with the Django template language.

In Django 1.7+, you can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with a custom `Prefetch` object when defining the queryset in the view.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    ...
    parents = Parent.objects.filter(
        children__male=True
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('children', queryset=Child.objects.filter(male=True), to_attr='male_children')
    )
```

Note that in the example above, you probably need to use `distinct()` to prevent duplicated parents for each male child.

We have used the `to_attr` argument as recommended in the docs. In the template, we then loop through the male children.

```
{% for parent in parents %}
    {{ parent.name }}
    {% for child in parent.male_children %}
        {{ child }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Awesome. I haven't tried it yet, but this will do exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Oh. And thank you for fixing/editing my model name. I'm not sure where Person came from.